# excel grid to columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, csv

I have data in an array/grid like this:

Name | Group | A1 | A2 | A3 
name1 | Group1 | 14.95 | 19.95 | 0.00
name2 | Group2 | 4.95 | 9.95 | 12.95
name3 | Group2 | 49.95 | 0.00 | 0.00

And I need a way (without VBA if possible) to turn the data in to 4 columns

name1 | Group1 | 14.95 | A1
name1 | Group1 | 19.95 | A2
name1 | Group1 | 0.00  | A3
name2 | Group2 | 4.95  | A1
name2 | Group2 | 9.95  | A2
name2 | Group2 | 12.95 | A3
name3 | Group2 | 49.95 | A1
name3 | Group2 | 0.00  | A2
name3 | Group2 | 0.00  | A3

I've tried paste-transpose and pivot tables, but everything I know requires lots of manual deletion to get the items to line up.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not really an answer, because outside the set boundaries of the OP questions, but it can be done using VBA as illustrated here: http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/705-excel-convert-table-to-list.html or here: http://michiel.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/convert-excel-tables-to-lists . Also, there are add-ins that can do this, like DigDB (http://www.digdb.com/excel_add_ins/transpose_crosstab_list/) or Kutools (http://www.extendoffice.com/product/kutools-for-excel/excel-convert-table-to-list.html)

Answer (score 0):

would use the Power Query Add-In for this. It does not require any code or complex functions. Starting from scratch it will probably take less than 5 minutes to complete this task.

You can start a Query from an existing Excel Table. I would then use the Unpivot command to transform the data as you require.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/unpivot-columns-HA104053356.aspx

The beauty of their implementation of Unpivot is that it will accept any further columns added (e.g. A4 , A5) and process them without any change in your Query definition.

I would rename columns as required and deliver the result to an Excel Table.